# Amending previous years tax return without filing a whole new return

Tags: united-states, taxes, amended-tax-return

I filed my 2019 tax return, but realised that I omitted about $40 of account interest. My account has said it'll cost $1000+tax to make the amendment. I'd rather just give IRS the whole $40. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Honestly for such a small amount, I wouldn’t waste the IRS’s time and yours. It will cost them **far** more than $10 to process your amended return. If they do happen to send you a bill, you can pay the tax along with the tiny penalty and interest. (But they won’t.)

Comment: How complicated is your tax situation, that a extra 1099-int causes a massive change? What documents/files do you have from your accountant?

Answer (score 2):

Do it yourself and mail it in:
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040x.pdf

Enclose a check made out to "U.S. Treasury" for the amount on line 20 of form 1040-X, "Amount You Owe."